# Ethernet Cable Not Working

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

My Wireless Adapter Broke Yesterday and i did not have the time to go and get a new one.
so i tried connecting with a Ethernet cable but ubuntu does not seem to recognize the cable at all. i tried setting up an new Ethernet connection but it does not seem to work!
How do you fix this?
If you need more info please ask.
Thanks! 
/Joel

Comment: Did you see any message on notification area "Connected" or "disconnected"? after you are pluging the cable?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my cable was causing the very same problem as you described. It took me some time but I noticed that after I right clicked on the WiFi/Ethernet icon in the panel there was an option "Auto Ethernet". After selecting it I was immediately connected through the Ethernet cable.

This was done on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score -1):

please first check the Ethernet cable is in working condition by plug in any another pc or laptop,then check the ip address and subnet mask in the setting,for that it would be good to contact your ISP they can configure the internet in better way as per your specification and requirements but don't forget to check the ethernet port of the system first...thanks,hope this help !!

Comment: It seems like my ethernet cable is not working on my pc so i will try with another one! Thanks For All The Answers!